# Yup validate either one of two fields is required (one of them is an array of numbers)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, formik, yup

I'm using Formik with Yup and Typescript, and I have this as an initial value of the form ...

```
const initialValues = {
    title: "",
    overview: "",
    related_items_id: [],
    short_desc: ""
};
```

And here's my schema ...

```
const formSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    title: Yup.string()
        .trim()
        .required("This field is required."),
    overview: Yup.string().required("This field is required."),
    related_items_id: Yup.array()
        .min(1, "Pick at least 1 item")
        .of(Yup.number().required("This field is required.")),
    short_desc: Yup.string().required("This field is required.")
});
```

Now, I need either the `related_items_id` array or the `short_desc` to be required, if one is filled with data the other is not required and vise Versa, how can I accomplish that using something like `when` in yup?

Here's a codesandbox I created to show the error that I'm getting when trying to use the `when` method of Yup ...

https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-yup-required-one-or-the-other-nextjs-gujqv

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a type that is interdepedent on  `related_items_id` and `short_desc`

```
export interface BaseType {
    title: string;
    overview: string;
}

interface RelatedItemsType extends BaseType {
  related_items_id?: Array<any>;
  short_desc?: never;
}

interface ShortDescType extends BaseType {
  related_items_id?: never;
  short_desc?: string;
}

export type InitialValueType = RelatedItemsType | ShortDescType;
```

and you can make use of it like this

```
const initialValues: InitialValueType = {
    title: "",
    overview: "",
    related_items_id: [],
    // short_desc: "" no longer required
};
```

For conditionally setting your formSchema, checkout the docs [Conditionally Set Required Field (Yup)](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema).

```
const basicFormSchema = Yup.object().shape(
    {
      title: Yup.string()
        .trim()
        .required("This field is required."),
      overview: Yup.string().required("This field is required."),
      related_items_id: Yup.array().when("short_desc", {
        is: "",
        then: Yup.array()
          .min(1, "Pick at least 1 item")
          .of(Yup.number().required("This field is required.")),
        otherwise: Yup.array()
      }),
      short_desc: Yup.string().when("related_items_id", {
        is: relatedItemsId => relatedItemsId.length === 0,
        then: Yup.string().required("This field is required."),
        otherwise: Yup.string()
      })
    },
    [["related_items_id", "short_desc"]]
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but could you please provide an example of how the schema would look like, as this is the confusing part for me, not the Typescript part.

Comment: I edited my answer with an example to how to go about it. @Ruby

Comment: Thanks my friend, I actually got this far before asking this question, it's just I always get this error ...
Cyclic dependency, node was:"short_desc". I don't know why. When I tried to google it, I found people doing it this way, but that didn't help me ...
https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/176#issuecomment-369925782

Comment: I think you should pass a third param to `Yup.object().shape` wich is an array, but I can't figure out what is the shape of that array would be. I'll try to make a Codesandbox demonstrate this.

Comment: Sure, create a sandbox and share it.

Comment: Here you go ...
https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-yup-required-one-or-the-other-nextjs-gujqv

Comment: @Ruby I've updated my answer with a working formSchema, you can check it out here https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-yup-required-one-or-the-other-nextjs-8yqbs

Comment: With this code none of them is required, you should get rid of the '?' for the value that is mandatory.

interface RelatedItemsType extends BaseType {
  related_items_id: Array<any>;
  short_desc?: never;
}

interface ShortDescType extends BaseType {
  related_items_id?: never;
  short_desc: string;
}

Answer (score 15):

If using `when` isn't a strict requirement, I find this is a little easier to do using the [test function](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schematestname-string-message-string--function--any-test-function-schema) as it's more concise, easier to follow, and doesn't require duplication of code or messages

```
const has = require('lodash.has'); // lodash's submodule

validationSchema = {                                                                                         
    Yup.object().shape({                                                                                 
            'email': Yup.string(),                                                                  
            'mobile': Yup.string(),
    })
    .test(
        'email or mobile',
        'email or mobile is required',
        (value) => has(value, 'email') || has(value, 'mobile')
    );
```

Comment: This should be the default answer. It's the shortest and most concise.

Comment: How to return an error message?

Comment: This seems to be most natural solution to me

Answer (score 14):

This is how you check if at least one of them is completed.

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  'fieldOneName': Yup.string()
  .when('fieldTwoName', {
    is: (fieldTwo) => !fieldTwo || fieldTwo.length === 0,
    then: Yup.string()
      .required('At least one of the fields is required'),
  }),
  'fieldTwoName': Yup.string()
  .when(codiceFiscale.name, {
    is: (fieldOne) => !fieldOne || fieldOne.length === 0,
    then: Yup.string().
      .required('At least one of the fields is required'),,
  })
}, ['fieldOneName', 'fieldTwoName']) // <-- HERE!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: Your array `['fieldOneName', 'fieldTwoName']` should be wrapped in another array. This may be due to an update, I'm not sure. See docs: https://github.com/jquense/yup#objectshapefields-object-nosortedges-arraystring-string-schema

Also, could you add an explanation for what that argument does? Thank you!

Comment: It appears that the documentation is poor on that field and it's sort of an experimental field: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59783667/yup-validate-either-one-of-two-fields-is-required-one-of-them-is-an-array-of-nu

Answer (score 8):

```
<Formik
            initialValues={{
                email: '',
                mobile: '',
                submit: null,
            }}

            validationSchema = {                                                                                         
    Yup.object().shape({                                                                                 
            'email': Yup.string()                                                                        
                        .when('mobile', {                                                    
                        is: (mobile) => !mobile || mobile.length === 0,                      
                        then: Yup.string()                                                   
                        .required('At least one of the fields is required'),                 
                                    }),                                                                  
            'mobile': Yup.string()                                                                       
                        .when('email', {                                                     
                        is: (email) => !email || email.length === 0,                         
                        then: Yup.string()
                        .required('At least one of the fields is required')
                        })                                                                   
    }, ['email', 'mobile'])                                                                              
}
```

Comment: I tried this with ustid and taxnumber, but get an error. 

Error: Cyclic dependency, node was:"taxnumber"

But i'm not shure what this does mean.

Comment: Ahh I was blind and forget to use .shape({...}, [['field', 'field2']])

I my sorry and will buying glasses now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Yup.object({
    linkedinLink: Yup.string()
      .trim()
      .nullable()
      .test('valid-linkedin-link', 'Invalid LinkedIn link', function (value) {
        if (!value) {
          return true;
        }
        return /^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?linkedin\.com\/(in|company)\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?:\/[\w-]+)*\/?$/.test(
          value
        );
      }),
    otherLink: Yup.string()
      .trim()
      .nullable()
      .test(
        'valid-other-link',
        'Enter correct url! ex:www.example.com',
        function (value) {
          if (!value) {
            return true;
          }
          return /^((https?|ftp|smtp):\/\/)?(www.)?[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z]{2,}){1,3}(#?\/?[a-zA-Z0-9#]+)*\/?(\?[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+=[a-zA-Z0-9-%]+&?)?$/.test(
            value
          );
        }
      ),
  }).test(
    'linkedinLink or otherLink',
    'linkedinLink or otherLink is required',
    (value) =>
      (value.linkedinLink ? value.linkedinLink.length > 0 : false) ||
      (value.otherLink ? value.otherLink.length > 0 : false)
  );
```

If both links are not present, it will result in an error. If at least one of them is present, the length should be greater than 0, and if the length is greater than 0, validation for each individual link will be performed.